# Quiz App MySQL better approach for storing questions/answers

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing quiz application using PHP and MySQL.

I'd like to create a quiz that one question could have as many answers as needed. Of course I will store all possible answers in MySQL and I'm going to display all possible answers in checkboxes where you can check any number of answers that are available.

The question is: what would be a good way to store all possible answers for a question when you don't want to limit yourself to a certain number of possible answers. Creating many columns for possible answers in one table wouldn't be optimal, that would be really inconvenient.

Should I save all possible answers in one column and separate them by delimiter so that I could extract each one with PHP?

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why not store the answers in another table with a column saying which question they relate to? You've almost exactly described a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like Knells mentions, you could create something like this:

```
create table questions (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  question text,
  primary key (id)
);

create table answers (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  answer text,
  primary key (id)
);

create table question_answers (
  question_id int not null,
  answer_id int not null,
  constraint fk_q_a_question_id foreign key (question_id) references questions (id),
  constraint fk_q_a_answer_id foreign key (answer_id) references answers (id),
  primary key (question_id, answer_id)
);
```

Alternately you could even do:

```
create table questions (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  question text,
  primary key (id)
);

create table answers (
  id int not null auto_increment,
  answer text,
  question_id int not null,
  primary key (id),
  constraint fk_answers_question_id foreign key (question_id) references questions (id)
);
```

With the first option, you can reuse an answer for as many questions as you like. With the second option, you can use an answer for only one question. Both options allow you to enter as many answers you want for a given question.